# php двумерный массив из имен файлов и их размеров

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

У меня есть код, который ищет файлы в папке, как его доработать, чтобы он создавал массив из имен файлов и их размеров и рассортировать этот массив по размерам файлов.

Код:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__). '/'.$wldir);
$array = array();
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    
    $fis = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    $sizefis = $fileinfo->getSize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так можно

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
$array = [];

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->getType() == 'dir')
        continue;
    
    $item = [];
    $item['name'] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    $item['size'] = $fileinfo->getSize();
    $array[] = $item;
}

function sort_function_asc($a, $b) {
    return $a["size"] - $b["size"];
}

usort($array, "sort_function_asc");
var_dump($array);
```

Использованные функции:

[gettype()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/directoryiterator.gettype) тип перебираемого элемента

[usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort) сортировка ассоциативного под массива